# Identifying time periods in Pandas dataframe with less than indicated amount of instances required

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

## Data Sample

```
# copy the data to the clipboard, and read in with
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', index_col=[0])
,SITE_NUMBER,OBSERVATION_TIME,TMR_SUB_18,year,month,day,hour
4812338,128,2016-07-01 00:00:00+00:00,61.45,2016,7,1,0
4812339,128,2016-07-01 01:00:00+00:00,61.46,2016,7,1,1
4812340,128,2016-07-01 02:00:00+00:00,61.45,2016,7,1,2
4812341,128,2016-07-01 03:00:00+00:00,61.42,2016,7,1,3
4812342,128,2016-07-01 04:00:00+00:00,61.41,2016,7,1,4
4783900,128,2016-07-02 12:00:00+00:00,61.02,2016,7,2,12
4783901,128,2016-07-02 13:00:00+00:00,61.06,2016,7,2,13
4783902,128,2016-07-02 14:00:00+00:00,61.08,2016,7,2,14
4783912,128,2016-07-03 00:00:00+00:00,60.97,2016,7,3,0
4783913,128,2016-07-03 01:00:00+00:00,60.94,2016,7,3,1
4783914,128,2016-07-03 02:00:00+00:00,60.93,2016,7,3,2
4783915,128,2016-07-03 03:00:00+00:00,60.93,2016,7,3,3
4783916,128,2016-07-03 04:00:00+00:00,60.93,2016,7,3,4
4816940,128,2016-07-04 00:00:00+00:00,61.17,2016,7,4,0
4816941,128,2016-07-04 01:00:00+00:00,61.16,2016,7,4,1
4816942,128,2016-07-04 02:00:00+00:00,61.15,2016,7,4,2
4816943,128,2016-07-04 03:00:00+00:00,61.16,2016,7,4,3
4793109,128,2016-07-05 12:00:00+00:00,60.99,2016,7,5,12
4793110,128,2016-07-05 13:00:00+00:00,61.01,2016,7,5,13
4793111,128,2016-07-05 14:00:00+00:00,61.02,2016,7,5,14
4793112,128,2016-07-05 15:00:00+00:00,61.04,2016,7,5,15
4793113,128,2016-07-05 16:00:00+00:00,61.05,2016,7,5,16
4782144,128,2016-07-06 12:00:00+00:00,61.01,2016,7,6,12
4782145,128,2016-07-06 13:00:00+00:00,60.99,2016,7,6,13
```

### Defining the data

This data is temperature data that is hourly throughout the entire year. The sample features one station (out of several), one year and month (2016, July), with a few days and few sample hours

### The Task

We need to employ a QC rule to identify days with less than 24 hours (in the sample, the QC would be less than 5 hours). The TMR_SUB_18 field needs to be replaced with **Null** for the entire day if a day has less than the required amount of hours.

### What I've Tried

*psuedo-pandas*

```
for name, group in df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'day']):
    if group.shape[0] < 5:
        group.TMR_SUB_18 = np.nan
        df.update(group)
```

This seems to work fine, but the entire dataset is 5754574 rows with multiple SITES, Years, and their respective months days. the QC test will eventually apply to days of months and months of years - i'm not entirely sure how to accomplish this without doing the same repeated for loop over and over

**is there a more efficient or recommended process to accomplish different levels of iteration processes of pandas groupby's?**

Please advise how I can construct this question to be more clear.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work - you're doing a `df.TRM_SUB_18 = np.nan` in your loop, which will make the entire column for the entire df nan

Comment: covert the date to yyyymmdd integer and then groupby() the one variable?  5M rows is not that much, consider the number of rows in one-day trading at microseconds.
Once you have the row ID by yyyymmdd kill that day...

Comment: @Chris, you are right, i shifted gears in my approach while writing this question. A deadly mistake. my original approach was to use a for loop to make layers of groupby's. Then the last step was the "day" groupby which if was less than 5, which became nan. i had intended to insert those values back to the original dataframe, but i felt there was a more simple and better way, so i changed. Sorry for the mix-up. i'll try to adjust the original question accordingly.

Comment: @PaulBrennan, i did consider something similar, but not converting to an integer and using that. I will attempt to try that and let you know! Thanks for the input